Why we use Binarycrossentropy as loss function of logistic regression model?
Let's say we have a logistic regression model:
$$z = \vec w \cdot \vec x + b$$
$$a_1 = g(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}} = P(y=1|\vec x)$$
$$a_2 = 1-a_1 = P(y=0|\vec x)$$
$$loss = -yln(a_1)-(1-y)ln(1-a_1) $$
where y is the target class, then our cost function will be
$$J(\vec{w}, b) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \text{loss}^{(i)}$$
My question is why do we use cross entropy as the lost function instead of another function?
I know it is related to maximum likelihood estimation but I don't know the deatils

You might enjoy my answer here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/622284/97124
